# Change Rating range in Link Manager

Tags: functions, links, rating

I have looked in here and across the internet but I can not seem to find an answer.
Is there a way to change the values of the ratings. By Default it seems to be 0 to 10, but I can not find a way to modify this feature to something like 0 to 20 or something.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the function `link_advanced_meta_box()` in `wp-admin/includes/meta-boxes.php`:

```
<td><select name="link_rating" id="link_rating" size="1">
<?php
    for ( $r = 0; $r <= 10; $r++ ) {
        echo '<option value="' . $r . '"';
        if ( isset($link->link_rating) && $link->link_rating == $r )
            echo ' selected="selected"';
        echo('>' . $r . '</option>');
    }
?></select>&nbsp;<?php _e('(Leave at 0 for no rating.)') ?>
```

The value is hard-coded.

You could deregister the metabox `'linkadvanceddiv'` and register your own instead.

Be aware the link manager has [no future](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/21307). I would use a custom post type instead with specialized meta data handling.

Comment: I agree completely, The links manager is pretty much designed to do exactly what I need it to do for this one piece of functionality. Other wise I would have taken more time to develop a better solution. thanks for the help!